# Auto focus text field in M3 Smart Office

Tags: text, focus, field

I needed to auto focus on a text field when we proceed through the panels.  in M3 smart office, where it uses java.

Further understanding of question look for the pic.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHI0J.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYLDe.png)

When we proceed through the panel by going "NEXT". M3 focus to "Co resp" text field, as it shown in the pic. 
I need it to focus to "Salesperosn" field.

A clue or a function to be look through would be helpull.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user personalization (in the panel it's under the Tools menu) where you set the tab order. Focus will follow the tab order. So you can change it to start at the field that you like and then order the fields as you like. But keep in mind that if M3 has a validation error it might override your suggestion of focus and place it in any field that it sees fit, for example after a validation error.